# pass parameter on import with codesplitting

Tags: reactjs, react-router, code-splitting

I have code like below and I want to pass athlete to:

- `AthleteInfo`
- `AthleteGroups`
- `AthleteContactInfo`
- `AthleteCompetitionHistory`

I have tried looking for a few different searches like, "code splitting with params react" and "pass parameter on import with code splitting" but haven't found anything that has given me any confidence.  The results usually include suspense, lazy, and loadable.  Is that what I am looking for, or do I need a different implementation?

```
import "../style/athlete.css"
import AthleteInfo from "./components/AthleteInfo";
import AthleteGroups from "./components/athleteQuickLinks/components/AthleteGroups";
import AthleteContactInfo from "./components/athleteContactInfo/AthleteContactInfo";
import AthleteQuickLinks from "./components/athleteQuickLinks/AthleteQuickLinks";
import AthleteCompetitionHistory from "./components/athleteCompetitionHistory/AthleteCompetitionHistory";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const{ athlete } = useParams()

const Athlete = () => {
  return (
    <div className='Athlete'>
      <AthleteInfo />
      {/<AthleteQuickLinks />/}
      <AthleteGroups />
      <AthleteContactInfo />
      <AthleteCompetitionHistory />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Athlete;
```

Comment: The `useParams` can't be called outside a React component or custom React hook. Have you tried passing `athlete` as a prop, e.g `<AthleteInfo athlete={athlete} />` If not and this isn't the issue then your post/question is quite unclear what you are asking for help with or what any issue is.

Comment: code-splitting refers to splitter your code into different bundles. That decreases the initial load time of the app for a user as the initial bundle is smaller. And yes that's called 'lazy loading'. That required suspense for it to properly load for the user. And you can pass in props as in any other component (lazy loaded or not) in the same manner

Comment: and, as Drew said, `useParams` is a hook that can only be used inside of the functional component. move it in